# how to use regex to extract match string in scala?

Tags: scala

The string is given as

```
var filedate = parser("test_pb_PP_Quality_2-Report_20200707.csv");
```

The Parser function to extract "20200707" as below.

```
def parser(filename: String):String = {
    val extractDate = """(\d{8}).*""".r
    val extractDate(dd) = filename;
    dd;
}
```

But its return error as Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, a Regex created with the `.r` method is anchored, which means it must match the whole string. (think of your regex as being enclosed in `^` and `$` )

You could use an unanchored regex instead:

```
def parser(filename: String):String = {
  val extractDate = """(\d{8})""".r.unanchored
  val extractDate(dd) = filename
  dd
}
```

This works, but is bad practice since "parsing" would throw an exception if your input does not match. More idiomatic would be to return an `Option[String]` and handle that at the calling site. For example:

```
def parser(filename: String): Option[String] = {
  """\d{8}""".r.findFirstIn(filename)
}

parser("test_pb_PP_Quality_2-Report_20200707.csv") match {
  case Some(datetime) => // do something
  case None           => // handle this case
}
```

Comment: .unanchored exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Java's `String#replaceAll` here:

```
def parser(filename: String):String = {
    val extractDate = filename.replaceAll(".*(\\d{8}).*", "$1");
    extractDate;
}

println(parser("test_pb_PP_Quality_2-Report_20200707.csv"))
```

This prints:

```
20200707
```

Comment: could we used regex for the same?

Comment: Well...this answer _is_ using regex, if you look closely `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Just allow some text before the numbers by adding `.*` to the beginning of the regular expression:

```
def parser(filename: String):String = {
    val extractDate = """.*(\d{8}).*""".r
    val extractDate(dd) = filename;
    dd;
}
```

You could also use a match-expression to handle the case where the filename does not have the expected format:

```
def parser(filename: String):String = {
    val extractDate = """.*(\d{8}).*""".r
    filename match {
      case extractDate(dd) => dd
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Invalid filename $filename")
    }
}
```